# Showing countdown timer on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I find a code for setting countdown timer but it only shows minutes not seconds when page is load and also I want that when user click on button then countdown should start and also time (e.g 10:59) should be shown on the clicked button.
Following is the code:

aspx code (ASP.net C#)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reservation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reservation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerTimer" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>
       <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" 
        runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btnTimer" runat="server" BackColor="#05CC00" Height="35px" Text="Reserve" Width="89px" style="border-radius:8px" OnClick="btnTimer_Click"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
       </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Reservation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!ScriptManagerTimer.IsInAsyncPostBack)
            Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).ToString();
    }

    protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
       DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
        {
            btnTimer.Text = ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
            ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Minutes).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you need someone else to modify a code that you found some other place else, to meet your need!!. Don't you think you should have shown a little more dignity? The solution would have been even easier than spending 15 minutes asking.

Comment: So basically you don't know how to do it or you don't want to help me

Comment: ooh! wait i don't want your help!

Comment: Well honestly, you need help. That is why you asked. What I mentioned is that, SO is not about asking and getting something. This is not a program store. We are programmers just like you. We solve problems to help others.  Since we are spending our time solving your problems, we also appreciate same from you. If you haven't spent some time trying to modify the code to try for yourself, how do you expect others to spent time on your problem? You are copying a code from other place to here and asking the solution. That is not nice. Show some effort that you tried, what worked and what didn't?.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
   DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
    {

        btnTimer.Text = ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Minutes).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

`TimeSpan.ToString()` offers a variety of string formats. More info : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx)

:)